If a curve intersects a propperly embbeded submanifold, then it is contained in that submanifold
I saw this problem in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:
Suppose that $S\subseteq M$ is a propperly embbeded submanifold and let $V\in\frak{X}$$(M)$ such that $V$ is tangent to $S$ (i.e $V_p\in T_pS$ for every $p\in S$). Show that for any integral curve $\gamma$ of $V$ that intersects $S$, $\gamma$ is contained in $S$.
Is my argument correct?
Let's say $\gamma :I\longrightarrow M$  is an integral curve of $V$.
I already proved that if $t_0\in I$ is such that $\gamma(t_0)\in S$, then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\gamma(t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon)\subseteq S$ (this is relatively easy to prove so I don't think I need to explain it. One could even (informally) say that we take a Taylor expansion of the representation of $\gamma(t_0)$ and since $T_pS\leq T_pM$ we get what we want).
Let's just say that $\gamma(t_0)\in S$. Suppose there is $t^*>t_0$ so that $\gamma(t^*)\notin S$. Let's consider the subset of $I$ such that $\gamma([t_0,t])\subseteq S$. This set is bounded and therefore, let $\alpha$ be the suppremum of this set. Then, consider a sequence $t_n\uparrow \alpha$ ($t_n>t_0$). We get a sequence $\gamma(t_n)$ which is contained in $S$ and whose limit is $\gamma(\alpha)$. Since $S$ is propperly embbeded, then it is closed and therefore $\gamma(\alpha)\in S$, but this implies that there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that the image of $(\alpha-\varepsilon,\alpha+\varepsilon)$ is in $S$ which is contradiction to what we assumed of $\alpha$ being the suppremum.
Then, $\gamma(I)$ is fully contained in $S$
